# Problem Upload Image/File in different devices with Retrofit, Got an Error Code:500 or Internal Server Error

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to Upload image/file using retrofit 2 here is my code

this is my Interface

`@POST("Upload/UploadFile")
 Call<ResponseUpload> postImage (@Body RequestBody files);`

and this my method for post to web service

```
    File fotoKTP = new File(Uri.parse(pathKTP).getPath());
    File fotoSelfie = new File(Uri.parse(pathSelfie).getPath());

    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    builder.addFormDataPart("phone_number", regisUser.getNo_hp());
    builder.addFormDataPart("foto_id",fotoKTP.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), fotoKTP));
    builder.addFormDataPart("foto_selfie",fotoSelfie.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), fotoSelfie));

    MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();

    Call<ResponseUpload> call = client.postImage(requestBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseUpload>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseUpload> call, Response<ResponseUpload> response) {
            ResponseUpload responseUpload = response.body();
            if (responseUpload != null){
                if (responseUpload.getSuccess().equals("1")) {
                    flag = true;
                    regisUser.setFoto_id(responseUpload.getFoto_id());
                    regisUser.setFoto_selfie(responseUpload.getFoto_selfie());
                    Toast.makeText(AutentikasiActivity.this, "Url Foto : " + responseUpload.getFoto_id() + "dan" + responseUpload.getFoto_selfie(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (responseUpload.getSuccess().equals("-9")) {
                    flag = false;
                    Toast.makeText(AutentikasiActivity.this, "Balikan Dari Server :" + responseUpload.getError_msg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AutentikasiActivity.this, "Response Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseUpload> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(AutentikasiActivity.this, "Check Your Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

my problem is Why i got Internal Server Error/Code : 500 when using different devices.

I tested with my device Lenovo K6 Note Android 7 API 23 it Worked Perfectly and i got code: 200 which mean is a success, but when i tested with my friend device OnePlus 5 T which is Android 8.1 API 27 it got error code : 500 "internal server error", i already tested to with third device Samsung Note FE Android 8.1 API 27 it got some error code. Does anyone know how to solve and a solution for this problem? thx.

Answer (score 0):

This is no real solution, but if you are also the author or admin of the backend I would try to check what kind of data your backend has received and what the server logs say why the backend script has failed as 500 is a server error.

Comment: Thanks for your replied, but you see i already check backend but its not my backend problem, i already check my post on a trace log but when i used that 2 Device (Samsung and OnePlus 5 T) the trace log is empty and i doesn't send anything from that device on the other hand my device Lenovo the trace log show my file and my json, are this problem because of Higher API such as API 27?

Comment: Have you tried logging the client site by adding logging to Retrofit with `HttpLoggingInterceptor`?

Comment: Not yet, i will try your advice, thank you for your time